# Client-Server Application based on AZURE

Tags: azure, sockets, networking, client-server

I have a simple client-server (master slave) UDP application which runs perfectly on local machine as well as between two different machines. i.e. I can send data from client and receive it on server.

My next step is to run the client on a VM on AZURE and read the data from the server (i.e. Master or my PC) on the AZURE VM. For this, i am running the client on AZURE and giving it the IP address of my local machine i.e. Master in this case. But somehow there is no communication.

What i fear is that the firewall is blocking some functionalities. I have also opened Port 53 (for UDP) on AZURE and tried to bind the socket on this port but this also does not help.

Here is the code for my server side which is running locally on my PC :

```
void main( ){

//WinSock_Init();

WSADATA data;
WORD version = MAKEWORD(2,2);
int wsok = WSAStartup(version, &data);
if(wsok != 0)
{
    cout<< "cant start Winsock!"<<wsok<<endl;
    //return;
}


SOCKET in = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
sockaddr_in server;
server.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = ADDR_ANY ;
server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_port = htons (54000);

if (bind(in, (sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(server)) == SOCKET_ERROR){

    cout << "cant bind the socket!"<<WSAGetLastError<<endl;
}

sockaddr_in client;
int clientLength = sizeof(client);
ZeroMemory(&client,clientLength);

char buffer[1024];



 while (1)
{
    ZeroMemory(buffer,1024);
    int bytesIN = recvfrom(in,buffer,1024,0,(sockaddr*)&client,&clientLength);

    if(bytesIN == SOCKET_ERROR){

        cout << "error receiving from client"<<WSAGetLastError()<<endl;
        continue;
    }

    // Display message and client info

    char clientIP[256];
    ZeroMemory(clientIP, 256);

    inet_ntop(AF_INET, &client.sin_addr, clientIP,256);

    cout<<"Received message from "<<clientIP<<" : "<<buffer<<endl;

}

closesocket(in);

WSACleanup();}
```

And this is the client side code with the IP address of my local machine i.e. "10.19.206.13" :

```
void main(int argc,char* argv[] ){

//WinSock_Init();

WSADATA data;
WORD version = MAKEWORD(2,2);
int wsok = WSAStartup(version, &data);
if(wsok != 0)
{
    cout<< "cant start Winsock!"<<wsok<<endl;
    return;
}
sockaddr_in server;
server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_port = htons(54000);
inet_pton(AF_INET, "10.19.206.13", &server.sin_addr);

SOCKET out = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

string s(argv[1]);
int sendok = sendto(out, s.c_str(), s.size() + 1,0, (sockaddr*) &server, sizeof(server));

if (sendok == SOCKET_ERROR)

{
    cout<<"that didnt work"<<WSAGetLastError()<<endl;
}

closesocket(out);

WSACleanup();}
```

This is the current Inbound rules on my AZURE VM where I have already allowed traffic on port 53 i.e. for UDP.

> **NOTE : I have also tried to bind the socket on port 53 on the client and server side but it did not help. Do i need to make some changes in the firewall of my local PC ? I know i am missing some basic but just cannot get it running.**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PaPpe.png)

Comment: When you say opened port 53, was this in the VM's “Inbound security rules”.

Comment: Yes, you can also see that on the image attached. @MurrayFoxcroft

Comment: Did you set a similar rule on the vnet to accept port 53 from any?

Comment: you mean on my PC's firewall ? @jwmiller5

Comment: The vm will have the windows firewall, but the virtual network associated with the vm can also have a network security group that is filtering traffic. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/security-overview Is port 53 open in both places?